# How to plot a hexagon inscribed on a cylinder in 3D? The cylinder is hollowed out in the form of a hexagon (Mathematica)

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization, mathematica-online

I want to plot a hexagon inscribed on a cylinder in 3D using Mathematica.

Edit1: I would like to define its direction by means of a vector

Comment: Please display the code you have tried in Mathematica format in your question.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** The function `regularPrism[{xyz1, xyz2}, radius, n]` constructs the graphics primitives for an n-gonal prism inscribed in `Cylinder[{xyz1, xyz2}, radius]`:

```
ClearAll[regularPrism, tF]
tF = TranslationTransform[#[[1]]]@*
    RotationTransform[{{0, 0, Norm[#[[2]] - #[[1]]]}, #[[2]] - #[[1]]}] &;

regularPrism[c_: {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, r_: 1, n_: 6] := 
 Module[{coords = Join @@ (Map[Append[#]] @ CirclePoints[r, n] & /@ 
     {0, Norm[c[[2]] - c[[1]]]}), 
   indices = Join[{#, n + #}, 
       Map[Flatten @ {#, n + Reverse @ #} &] @ Partition[#, 2, 1, 1]] & @ Range[n]}, 
  GraphicsComplex[tF[c]@coords, Polygon[indices]]]
```

**Examples:**

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5, Red], 
  regularPrism[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, 1/2], Opacity[.3, Blue], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, 1/2]}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]; 
randomcoords = Round[RandomReal[10, {9, 2, 3}], .1]; 

Multicolumn[Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5, Red], regularPrism[#, 1], 
   Opacity[.2, Blue], Cylinder[#, 1]},
  Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 300,  PlotLabel -> Cylinder[#, 1]] & /@ 
 randomcoords, 3]
```

[image]

Use `regularPrism[#, 1, 3]` to get

[image: ![enter image description here]

and `regularPrism[#, 1, 8]` to get

[image]

**Original answer:**

**1.** [`RegionProduct`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionProduct.html) + [`RegularPolygon`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegularPolygon.html) + [`RegionPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot3D.html)

```
Show[RegionPlot3D[RegionProduct[RegularPolygon@6, Line[{{-1}, {1}}]], 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5, Red], Boxed -> False], 
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[.2, Green], Cylinder[]}]]
```

[image]

**2.** [`PolyhedronData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolyhedronData.html)

```
prism6 = PolyhedronData[{"Prism", 6}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.3, LightBlue], 
  Cylinder[], 
  Opacity[.5, Red], 
  Scale[First @ prism6, {1, 1, 2}]}, 
 Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh I forgot to speak, but I would like to define its direction by means of a vector, like this:
Ex:
Origin {0,0,0} to {1,1,1}

Graphics3D [Cylinder [{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, 1/2]]

Comment: @YhanVonchesty, please see the update.